# Calculate the difference in days between dates between rows in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have a date column. What formula do I use in Google Sheets to calculate the difference in days between rows?

I tried `=DATEDIF(A2,A3,"D")` but get the following:

[image: screenshot showing formula and referenced cells]

Answer (score 3):

#### I tried `=DATEDIF(A2,A3,"D")` but get `#NUM!`

> Warning: I﻿f the Start_date is greater than the End_date, the result will be `#NUM!`.

Source: [Calculate the difference between two dates - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38)

Try reversing the dates:

```
=DATEDIF(A3,A2,"D")
```

Comment: Function DATEDIF parameter 1 (9/25/2021) should be on or before Function DATEDIF parameter 2 (7/27/2021).

Comment: 25 sep is **not** on or before 27 jul.

Comment: thx I done that, and the output is

1900/02/28

was expecting something like 50

Comment: @Nikos That's because your output column is formatted as a date - it should be formatted as a number.